# Edit product - change image

Tags: php, mysql, filenames, rename

I have in the database products, and each product has a image, I'm thinking to save image with `$filename = sprintf('%08d', $id);`

But for products I have also edit section, where I can change the image, which would be the best approach for changing image? It's ok if I save the new image with the old image name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either way. Depending on you app. If it's for example a user picture, then leave the old name as name is irrelevant but the content is important (a picture) and update a file content. If however,  picture defines the content then replace the name of the image. In your case i would put the new name as image defines the content (i.e. large_image_red_productname.jpg)

Ideally, you should name the product image as a product name(i.e. product_name.jpg) regardless of what file name is uploaded.

Comment: naming images product_name.jpg is be relevant for search engines? Or search engines use just alt attribute when searching images?

Comment: @morandi3 What ideally you shoudl do is to name the product_image as your product. and then when image si updated your update teh content and leave the image.

Comment: @Elijan I'm talking about the case when I update also another image for one product

Comment: #morandi3 when you update an image or when you add another image for same product? if latter is the case just ad number later i.e. product_name_1.jpg. If you update an image just update a content of a file. leave the name.

Comment: @morandi3 So leave name as it is. just update the image. As fro search engines it woudl be good if image had relevant name, however, even images are searched depending  the content they are displayed  on.